# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el ingreso de espacios en un scanf?

Tags: c

Necesito que alguien me diga cómo puedo realizar la validación de entrada de datos cuando el usuario ingresa un número, pero con espacios en c, como por ejemplo si ingresan 1 2 que pueda tomar 12 y no solo 1. Dejo un código para que me digan qué agregar para poder borrar ese espacio.

```
int Fibo(int k){
    int resultado;
    if (k < 1)
    {
        resultado = k + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        resultado = Fibo(k - 1) + Fibo(k - 2);
    }
    return resultado;
}

int validarK(){
    int k, resultado;

    printf("Ingresa el numero K: ");
    resultado = scanf("%d", &k);

    while (resultado != 1 || k < 0){
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Dato incorrecto. Ingresa denuevo: ");
        resultado = scanf("%d", &k);
    }

    return k;
}

int main(){
    int k;
    k = validarK();
    printf("El resultado es: %i", Fibo(k));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: El problema es el espacio entre "1 2" al usar scanf(), te sugiero en este caso usar fgets(), revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: Pues debes de convertir la cadena en texto y luego quitar todos los espacios, luego convertir la cadena numero para conseguir el valor

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de `scanf()` te sugiero usar [`fgets()`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/es/i/7.5?topic=functions-fgets-read-string) para obtener toda la entrada como una sola cadena de carácteres, a partir de esto puedes convertir cada elemento a entero y obtener el resultado correcto.

De acuerdo a tu código original realiza los cambios siguientes para que funcione correctamente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int Fibo(int k){
    int resultado;
    if (k < 1)
    {
        resultado = k + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        resultado = Fibo(k - 1) + Fibo(k - 2);
    }
    return resultado;
}

int validarK(){
    int k; //, resultado;
    char resultado[100]; //*Define variable para almacenar entrada

    printf("Ingresa el numero K: ");
    //resultado = scanf("%d", &k);
    fgets(resultado, sizeof(resultado), stdin);

    /*while (resultado != 1 || k < 0){
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Dato incorrecto. Ingresa denuevo: ");
        resultado = scanf("%d", &k);
    }*/

    char *token = strtok(resultado, " ");
    k = 0;
    while (token != NULL) { //*Obtiene cada token y lo convierte a entero
        k = k * 10 + atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    printf("El resultado validarK()  es: %i\n", k);

    return k;
}

int main(){
    int k;
    k = validarK();
    printf("El resultado es: %i", Fibo(k));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: y como puedo hacer para verificar que el dato ingresado no sea una palabra? ya que yo necesito que el dato solamente sean numeros.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de hacerlo es leer toda la entrada en una cadena y luego procesarla con `sscanf`. Tu función para validar k sería algo como esto:

```
#define SIZE 256
int validarK(){
  char buffer[SIZE], trash[SIZE];
  int  k, resultado;
  
  for (;;) {
    printf("Ingresa el numero K: ");
    fgets (buffer, SIZE, stdin);
    resultado = sscanf(buffer, "%d %s", &k, &trash);
    
    if (resultado == 1 && k > 0) break;
    printf("Dato incorrecto. Ingresa de nuevo: \n");
  }
  
  return k;
}
```

Convertir una entrada como `1 2` en `12` es extraño. Si realmente lo quieres hacer, simplemente elimina los espacios de la cadena que lees, pero creo que eso es un error.